# BackBoneJs donot Delete/Update Model to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that reads/create/update model and save it to the server. But presently I am able to read and save my models from and to the database. But I am unable to delete / update the model from and to the server. currently the views gets deleted of the model but not the model it self
here is the JSFiddle path http://jsfiddle.net/u17xwzLh/1/

```
$(function() {
```

**Model**

```
    var modelContact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            Id: 0,
            Name: "",
            Address: ""
        };
    }, 
    //if i add this idAttribute = "Id" it deletes the value from the server 
    //but i am unable to create a new model/new entry to the database
    clear: function () {
        // Deletes the model but the changes are not posted back to the server
        this.destroy(); 
    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
// runs fine
var contactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: modelContact,
    url: 'api/Contact'
});

var contacts = new contactCollection;
```

**ModelView**

```
var contactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    events: { // runs fine
        "click a.destroy": "clear"
    },
    template: _.template($("#newContacttemplate").html()), // runs fine
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function() { // runs fine
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.model.clear();
    }
});
```

**MainView**

```
var main = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#contactApp"),
    events: { // runs fine
        "click #btnsave": "CreateNewContact"
    },
    initialize: function() { // runs fine
        this.Nameinput = this.$("#contactname");
        this.Addressinput = this.$("#contactaddress");
        contacts.on("add", this.AddContact, this);
        contacts.on("reset", this.AddContacts, this);
        contacts.fetch(); // Note : populates all the database values
    },
    AddContact: function(contact) { // runs fine
        var view = new contactView({ model: contact });
        this.$("#tblcontact tbody").append(view.render().el);
    },
    AddContacts: function() { // runs fine
        contacts.each(this.AddContact);
    },
    CreateNewContact: function(e) { // runs fine
        contacts.create({ Name: this.Nameinput.val(), Address: this.Addressinput.val() });
    }
});
var m = new main;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a `URL` defined on your `Backbone.Collection` but not on your `Backbone.Model`, which means you have to do all AJAX work through the `Collection`.  It doesn't have to be that way though: you can add a second URL on yours server-side for `Model` AJAX operations, or the two could even share a URL (if you set it up appropriately).

The important part, if you want to be able to call `this.destroy();` and have it reflected on your server, is that you need:

1. a URL on your server that can handle requests with the DELETE method (vs. the usual GET or POST methods)
2. a `url` property on your `Backbone.Model` that is set to that server-side URL

Once you have that your call to `this.destroy();` will create a DELETE AJAX request, your server will receive that request and know that it should delete the appropriate database record, and then that model will be deleted on both the client- and server-side.

Comment: I have added this on my Model
 url: 'api/Contact' but it still does not reflect back to the server. I have this method signature that handles delete request from both the Collection and model  "public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int Id)"

Comment: Try opening up your browser developer tools (eg. Chrome developer tools, Firebug, etc.) and then open the Net tab.  Then try triggering a `destroy` and see if an AJAX request for the `destroy` appears in the Net tab.  If it doesn't, something's wrong with your Backbone, if it does something's wrong with your server (in which case you might want to look at the request itself to see if it's what your server is expecting).